# Devise Security Extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, devise

I'm trying to use devise security extension as it has the exact methods I'm looking for for my project.
I've followed all the instructions on the github page: https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension, but when I try to run my project I get this error message:

> /home/felipe/ruby-example-2.4.1/ball-consulta-de-notas-fiscais/vportal/config/initializers/devise.rb:285:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method`expire_password_after=' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)

I've added the method `:password_expirable` to my user.rb and uncommented the line # Should the password expire (e.g 3.months)

```
config.expire_password_after = 2.months on my devise.rb
```

I'm running rails 5.0.

Can you please help me?

Comment: could you attach your Gemfile.lock, please?

Comment: Hi, Max. 
Gemfile and Gemlock: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzuzoDRRRTDFa0ZIVXNMaWJ6bTA

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please notice there is a new repo containing updates for Rails 5.[devise-security](https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security). I have detailed the issue in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572257/devise-security-extension-gem-is-not-maintained-is-there-other-repo/49572258#49572258)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `devise_security_extension` in your Gemfile.lock, also there is no `gem 'devise'` in your `Gemfile` as well.
So, just add two lines `gem 'devise'` and `gem 'devise_security_extension'` to your `Gemfile`. Then repeat actions from documentation:

[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started)

[Devise Security Extension](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension#getting-started)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: In fact, I've added those gems to the gemspec file of the submodule application.
I wasn't clear enough, but we have a submodule which is responsible for the authentication bit of the application. Whenever we add a gem to the gemspec file we are able to run bundle install to the main one.
I can assure you devise is currently working and at the moment we can validate login and psswrd properly. The problem is with the extension.
I've added the missing file to drive. Can you please check it out?

Comment: @user3677415 could you add config/initializers/devise.rb to drive, please?

Comment: do your Devise model have included modules, something like `devise :password_expirable, :secure_validatable, :password_archivable, :session_limitable, :expirable`?

Comment: Max, I've updated Drive with devise.rb and user.rb.
And yes, when I finished running bundle install (after including the gem) and rails generate, it automatically inserted some commented lines in devise.rb.
After that, I've uncommented the ones I wanted to use and I've added the methods in user.rb - in the current file I'm testing only password_expirable. But somehow, it says the method is undefined.