# devise_security_extension gem is not maintained nor updated to Rails 5, is there other repo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my current project we are using [devise_security_extension](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension). The project uses rails 4.2.5.2 and ruby 2.1.9.
We are in a process to update to Rail 5.1.5 with ruby 2.4.3.

Unfortunately this gem is not updated to Rails 5 and it's not maintained anymore. Also the version from rubygems, even is 0.10.0, is not containing the last changes from github.

That are some forks that solve partially the update, but the company that I work for do not allow to load from github.com, only from rubygems.org. Having something like:

```
gem 'devise_security_extension', '~> 0.10.0', git: 'https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension'
```

is not allowed.

Is there another repo that contains the changes for Rails 5 and also it is maintained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the discussion from this [issue](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension/issues/199), @natebird created a new repo: [devise-security](https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security).

With version 0.11, Support for Rails 5 is introduced.